# Full Json match with RestAssured

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured

I'm using REST-Assured to test some API. My API clearly respond with a JSON and according to the doc if this is the response:

```
{
    "id": "390",
    "data": {
        "leagueId": 35,
        "homeTeam": "Norway",
        "visitingTeam": "England",
    },
    "odds": [{
        "price": "1.30",
        "name": "1"
    },
    {
        "price": "5.25",
        "name": "X"
    }]
}
```

I could test like this:

```
@Test
public void givenUrl_whenSuccessOnGetsResponseAndJsonHasRequiredKV_thenCorrect() {
   get("/events?id=390")
      .then()
         .statusCode(200)
         .assertThat()
            .body("data.leagueId", equalTo(35)); 
}
```

Surely this is readable but I would a full comparison of the JSON (i.e.: this is the JSON response; this is a canned JSON - a resource file would be perfect - are those JSON equals?). Does REST-Assured offer something like that or I need to make it manually.

Comment: Have you looked into json schema validation: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-schema-validation

Comment: I don't need a schema validation. I need a _result_ validation (not only type but only value). This will be cumbersome with JSON Schema (supposing it is possible)

Answer (score 18):

Use RestAssured's JsonPath to parse the json file into a Map and then compare it with Hamcrest Matchers. This way the order etc didn't matter.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

...

JsonPath expectedJson = new JsonPath(new File("/path/to/expected.json"));

given()
    ...
    .then()
    .body("", equalTo(expectedJson.getMap("")));
```

Answer (score 7):

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) is exactly what you are looking for - you can perform a full **equality** match of a JSON payload in one step.

And for the cases where you have dynamic values (generated keys, timestamps) Karate provides a very elegant way for you to ignore (or just validate the format of) these keys.

One the primary motivations for creating Karate was to come up with a better alternative to REST-assured. You can refer to this document which can help you evaluate Karate and make a case for it in your organization: [Karate vs REST-assured](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ETTrdMVcBXaPjdKY-_67zCWBsi2Ctc5DIQUIfr02H7A).

Answer (score 3):

REST Assured does not support JSON comparison, only schema and parts of the body as you have in your question. What you can do is using Hamcrest's JSON comparitorSameJSONAs in [Hamcrest JSON SameJSONAs](http://www.datumedge.co.uk/hamcrest-json/apidocs/reference/uk/co/datumedge/hamcrest/json/SameJSONAs.html)

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for method without parsing json-file.

You can check the body size at the beginning using `Matchers.aMapWithSize(size)`, and then check the contents as usual.

Example:

```
@Test
public void getAccount_forbidden_whenUserIsAnonymous() {
    RestAssured
        .get("/account")
        .then()
        .statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
        .body("", Matchers.aMapWithSize(5),
              "timestamp", Matchers.notNullValue(),
              "status", Matchers.equalTo(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN),
              "error", Matchers.equalTo("Forbidden"),
              "message", Matchers.equalTo("Access Denied"),
              "path", Matchers.equalTo("/account"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Validate with JSON SCHEMA in RestAssured.

Try this code:

// Base Test [BaseTest.java]

```
public class BaseTest {

    protected RequestSpecification requestSpecificationToMerge = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setBaseUri("BASE URL")
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setFilter() {
        RestAssured.filters(new AllureRestAssured());
    }

}
```

// Test [Home.java]

```
public class Home extends BaseTest {
    
    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void getHome() {
        
        given()
        .spec(requestSpecificationToMerge)
        .basePath("/your endpoint")
        .when()
        .get()
        .then()
        .log().body()
        .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("home.json"));
    }
```

// JSON SCHEMA [home.json]

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "data",
        "meta",
        "status"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": ["array", "null"],
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "title",
                    "sorting"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "sorting": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "meta": {
            "type": ["object", "null"],
            "required": [
                "pagination"
            ],
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "current_page",
                    "per_page",
                    "total",
                    "total_page"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "current_page": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "per_page": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "total": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "total_page": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "code",
                "message_client",
                "message_server"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "enum": [
                        200,
                        404
                    ]
                },
                "message_client": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "message_server": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
String s = "{\"ip\": \"your_ip\"}";
given().log().all().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("http://ip.jsontest.com/").then().log().all().assertThat().body(containsString(s))
```

Not easy way: you can create custom matcher or use jsonpath, it has options to comapre jsons.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, rest-assured only provides capabilities to validate the schema as described [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-schema-validation).

However, it's quite simple to make an exact comparison using [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and [junit](http://junit.org).

We should write a function that compares a body returned by rest-assured with a file in the `resources` directory

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

void assertJsonEquals(String expectedJson, ResponseBodyExtractionOptions actualBody) throws IOException {
    Assert.assertNotNull("The request returned no body", expectedJson);

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Assert.assertEquals(
            mapper.readTree(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(expectedJsonPath)).openStream().readAllBytes()),
            mapper.readTree(body.asByteArray())
    );
}
```

Then, use it as shown below

```
final ResponseBodyExtractionOptions actualBody = given()
        .accept("application/json")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .when()
        .get("...")
    .then()
        .extract().body();
assertJsonEquals("expected-payload.json", actualBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of JSONAssert Library to match the entire JSON Response. I recently wrote a [blog](https://restservicestesting.blogspot.com/2021/07/comparing-json-responses-using-json-assert.html) on how to achieve it.

Below is the basic usage on how to use the library:

```
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
```