# Test a particular method with rest-assured in Java

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

I want to test a specific method in a class named AdRestService that has some @GET, @POST, etc. I want to test it from another testing class named AdRestServiceTest. I want to know how can I call a method in AdRestService from AdRestServiceTest and how can I test if the return is ok or not.

```
public class AdRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Ad get(@PathParam("id") Long adId) {
        return adService.get(adId); // This points to the DB
    }

}
```

Now the rest-assured testing :

```
public class AdRestServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AdRestService adRestService;

    @Test
    public void getAdTest() {
        given().
        when().
            get("website.com/ad").
        then().
            assertThat().
            statusCode(200).
        and().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        and().
            // ???
                // How can I call the method get(@PathParam("id") Long adId) from AdRestService and test if the return is correct ?
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are mixing up `integration` and `unit tests`. Rest-assured is used for integration tests, ergo they test whether your application server is responding properly to your defined requests. You would actually define a .json file with an expected answer and you would match that with the actual response to check whether the serialization of your application server is working properly.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531005/4934937) as an example.

If you want to test the methods in your `AdRestService`, you would write a common unit test and there is no need to use rest-assured.

Comment: You actually just call the function and compare it's output to something you expect.

Comment: Yes but if the function returns a json format, how can I test this ?