# Rest Assured - compare json response with local json file

Tags: json, string-comparison, rest-assured

I have a local json file test.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "test2"
  }
]
```

Class to read the json file

```
public static String getFileContent(String fileName){
        String fileContent = "";
        String filePath = "filePath";
        try {
            fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
            return fileContent;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            return fileContent;
        }
    }
```

I use rest assured to make the request and get same json response back

```
String fileContent= FileUtils.getFileContent("test.json");

    when().
       get("/testurl").
    then().
       body("", equalTo(fileContent));
```

This is what I got from local file

```
[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 1,\r\n    \"title\": \"test1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 2,\r\n    \"title\": \"test2\"\r\n  }\r\n]
```

This is the actual response:

```
[{id=1, title=test1}, {id=2, title=test2}]
```

Is there any better way to compare those two? I try to do something like `fileContent.replaceAll("\\r\\n| |\"", "");` but it just removed all the space `[{id:1,title:test1},{id:2,title:test2}]`
Any help? Or any ways that just compare the content and ignore newline, space and double quote?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full Json match with RestAssured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716665/full-json-match-with-restassured)

Comment: Refer the answer given by @Hac which uses Hamcrest Matchers.

Comment: @kaweesha - I checked that post before posting my answer, `expectedJson.getMap("")` doesn't work when the JSON is as an ArrayList, The working solution here is `expectedJson.getList("")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the following methods

**JsonPath :**

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.getFileContent("test.json");

    JsonPath expectedJson = new JsonPath(fileContent);
    given().when().get("/testurl").then().body("", equalTo(expectedJson.getList("")));
```

**Jackson :**

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.getFileContent("test.json");
String def = given().when().get("/testurl").then().extract().asString();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode expected = mapper.readTree(fileContent);
    JsonNode actual = mapper.readTree(def);
    Assert.assertEquals(actual,expected);
```

**GSON :**

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.getFileContent("test.json");
String def = given().when().get("/testurl").then().extract().asString();

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement expected = parser.parse(fileContent);
    JsonElement actual = parser.parse(def);
    Assert.assertEquals(actual,expected);
```